# Is it ok to have any code before calling session_start()?

Tags: php

If I have `session_start();` at the top of my header page is it alright to include `$page_title` before the header page?

```
$page_title = 'Some Title';
include '../includes/header.php';
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.  As long as you don't output anything before it, you should be ok...

The reason is that `session_start` sends a few HTTP headers.  So if you've already outputted anything (including errors), it will fail, and as such won't start.

The way around that, is to setup output buffering at the top of the file.  Just make [`ob_start();`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) appear at the top of the page.  That way, no matter what happens (within reason), you should be ok (as in any output will be "captured" by the buffer, and hence not interfere with the session comamnd)...

**Edit:**  As requested, an example:

```
<?php
echo 'foo';
include '../includes/header.php';
```

Won't work since you've outputted something...

```
<?php
include 'non/existant/file.php';
include '../includes/header.php';
```

Won't work since the first `include` statement will emit a warning because it couldn't find the file...

```
FooBar<?php
include '../includes/header.php';
```

Won't work since you're outputting something before hand (the text before the `<?php` line)...

```
<?php
ob_start();
echo 'foo';
include '../includes/header.php';
```

WILL work, since the output is captured by the buffer...

```
FooBar<?php
ob_start();
include '../includes/header.php';
```

Will **not** work, since the output buffer is started *after* the output is started...

```
<?php
include 'some/valid/file.php';
include '../includes/header.php';
```

May or may not work.  It depends if the first included file outputs anything.  If it does, then it won't work (So toss a `ob_start()` before hand to try to ensure it works)...

Oh, and you'll likely want to change the [`include`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) to [`require`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) since you don't want to continue if it doesn't find the file...

Comment: what do you mean by output an example would be nice.

Comment: Output is anything that is printed to a page, e.g. with echo or print. Output buffering saves all of that in memory for output later. Look at ob_start() in the PHP manual.

Comment: @aatteot:  does that make sense and answer your question (the edit)?

Answer (score 1):

`session_start();` needs to appear before there's any actual output to the browser. Usually people put it above anything else simply to avoid confusion etc. but in this particular case you'll be ok as a variable assignation is not output.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

You cannot output anything to the browser before starting the session.

E.g. You cannot do this

```
echo "This will break";
session_start();
```

This is because the session is set in the page header, and by using echo/print or similar you are forcing output before the page header is sent, thus breaking the ability for the session to be correctly started.

Comment: You can do what ever you want, you just cannot output anything using functions like `echo`, `print`, `print_r`, `var_dump`, etc. You can do a query because it does not output anything, it just runs the query and returns the result. However, you cannot display the result of that query before using `session_start()`

Comment: Unless it raises an error...  Then it won't work (assuming that [`display_errors`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) is on)...